# sqlcmd utility returns "Could not find stored procedure"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using this command line utility:

```
sqlcmd -m 1 -S inxcert -U user1 -P u8er1 -i "D:\ESP\RunSQL.sql" -h -1 -o "D:\ESP\testoutput.txt"
```

Following is what I have written in RunSQL.sql:

```
exec spc.load_tables
```

Though the stored procedure exist in the database, credentials are correct and SQL Server runs fine when run from SSMS I am getting the following error in the output file:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server I0160SQL03\I0160SQL03, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'spc.mjr_vs_load_tables'.

Please help me to learn how to resolve the error.

Comment: Determine database like `USE DataBase exec spc.load_tables` or `exec DataBase.spc.load_tables`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's executing against the default database (probably `master`) so not finding your procedure.

Try either adding:

```
USE [DBNAME]
```

to `RunSQL.sql`, or specifying:

```
-d DBNAME
```

to your `sqlcmd` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for helping out but now in output file I am getting the following output: 
(595 rows affected)
     299425

(1 rows affected)
I just need the result, ie. 299425, how can I separate it from the others?

Comment: Alter your stored procedure, add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top. Or in your `RunSQL.sql` script.